# How to find if partition is soft partition or not - Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, administration

How to find if partition is soft partition or not in solaris 10?

Comment: Are you talking about `slices`?

Answer (score 0):

A hard partition will always have its device name as `/dev/dsk/cXtYdZsN`, where X, Y, Z and N are numbers.

If the device name is of the form `/dev/md/dsk/*`, then it's a Solaris Volume Manager metadevice - and that category includes soft partitions, mirrors, software RAID and other things. The output of `metastat` will tell you whether a metadevice is a soft partition or something else.